# React symbol evaluation. Caret and tilde symbol

Tags: reactjs, symbols

while reading React code, I encountered following statements using tilde and caret symbol, but couldn't figure out how it evaluates:-

```
const serviceUrl = `~^service, /enterprise/core-customer/example-path/${guid}/adresses/?purposes=PRIMARY, ^~`
```

Comment: Look for `~^` and `^~` strings in the project. They can be marks and then parsed somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those symbols are not part of JavaScript or React syntax.

Your project may have a custom parser (I'd start with looking into the function/component that `serviceUrl` is passed to). Or it may be implemented in an API your project calls.